# Javascript Button Error: Missing )

Tags: visualforce, javascript, button

I encounter this error:

> missing ) after argument list in javascript salesforce

when running the following:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js")} 


if('{!Account.Account_Checked__c}'==1){
window.open('https://c.ap12.visual.force.com/apex/AccountChecked');
} 
else{ 
window.open('_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Contact.Id}&p3={!Account.Name}&rtype=003&retURL=%2F{!Contact.Id}'); 
}
```

Comment: Can Some one help me what is missing there .. it worked perfectly fine till today morning .. but suddenly i got the error  some argument is missing

Comment: If the Account name includes a single quote the JavaScript would then be invalid. What is the Account name when this fails? Using `{!JSENCODE(Account.Name)}` would protect against that..

Comment: if('{(!Account.Account_Checked__c)}'==1)    I tried but still getting the same error

Comment: It does not sound like you used the advice from @KeithC then. You need to encode your strings using `JSENCODE()` to prevent invalid characters from creeping into your javascript string.

Comment: @KeithC Just post that as an answer! Seems likely enough to be the root cause. I'd upvote.

Comment: @AdrianLarson OK, turned into an answer.

Comment: @Revanth Also, consider comparing *inside* the merge field, because that'll be less brittle. Like this: `if({!Account.Account_Checked__c=1})`.

Answer (score 5):

If the Account name includes a single quote the JavaScript would then be invalid because that single quote would be interpreted as a string delimiter.

Using `{!JSENCODE(Account.Name)}` would protect against that as described in the [JSENCODE documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm):

> Encodes text and merge field values for use in JavaScript by inserting
>   escape characters, such as a backslash (), before unsafe JavaScript
>   characters, such as the apostrophe (').

Comment: Could you maybe also explain how to make this button work across environments? I notice the link structure is `https://c.ap12.visual.force.com/...`, which seems very brittle.